# Does Microsoft Edge Developer tool allow for integration of external programs/code

Tags: javascript, selenium

This [msedge-devtools image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYqNB.png) shows clearly what I'm trying to say. I'm looking to develop a webpage parser (in a way past JavaScript) through selenium and Microsoft Edge. I'm looking for a way therefore to use the Microsoft Edge developer tool (Inspect Element Mode) such that I can simply right click an element in the DevTool and select a **custom option** which calls for my program to obtain the data in that particular element. My question here is, can one add an option in the **options list** shown when you right click on an element in the **Element Inspection Mode** of the msedge DevTools.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand what all you are trying to do because you mention at least three things

1. Adding an option to the right-click list in the dev tools

   If you want to do this, you are probably talking about creating an add-in for Edge, which is unrelated to Selenium. Selenium drives the browser but doesn't interact with the UI of the browser.
2. Developing a webpage parser using Selenium and Edge

   You don't need Selenium or Edge to create a webpage browser. You can talk directly to the webserver and get the HTML of the page and do anything you want with it.
3. Click an element and "obtain the data in that particular element"

   It depends on what you mean by "obtain the data in that particular element". The existing functionality returns pretty much everything about that element. Have you looked carefully at what features are already available? I would start there because I'm assuming that whatever you want, it can already get you.

Comment: Well, your first point is used to achieve the third. In so doing the page will have been parsed; the second point which by the way you didn't quite understand (remember that parsing a page is different from creating one).

Comment: If you see my comment for #3, you will see that the functionality that you want already exists. If it doesn't, then you need to clarify in your question what specifically you are looking for. I never said anything about creating a page. You aren't bringing much clarity to what you are looking for. Please edit your question and ask only 1 question. Right now you seem to be asking 3.